# Uncaught Syntax Error jquery.js:1 when trying to load USMAP.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason in my console it's saying: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <jquery.js:1`  but I can't seem to find anything wrong with this code.. can anyone help me solve this annoying problem? Not really sure what's going on with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> {{ site_title }} </title> 
     <link href="{{ www }}stylesheets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ www }}stylesheets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ www }}stylesheets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src=
      "https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
     <script src="{{ www }}stylesheets/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
     <!-- user script -->
     <script type="text/javascript">
       {% if user is defined %}
       var user = {
        example: {{ userjson | raw }}
       };
       {% else %}
       var user = false;
       {% endif %}
     </script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/raphael.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/usmap.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/main.js"></script>
  <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/color.jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/states.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ www }}js/us-map.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
```

Comment: Why you're including jQuery thrice? And why is one in "stylesheets"? O.o

Comment: @Andreas all the legacy, duh

Comment: @Andreas it's custom jquery

Comment: Even if `js/jquery.js` is a custom script, you're still overwriting the 3.2.1 version (from the "stylesheets" folder) with version 1.6.2 from the google CDN.